# Change variable name while posting the object to http angular 6

Tags: typescript, http-post, angular6

```
    export class ShopModel {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public email: string;
    public phone: string;
    public website: string;
    public address: string;
    public gst_number: string;
    public pan_number: string;
    public tan_number: string;
    public plan_id: number;
    public status: number = 1;
    public users: UserModel[];
    public customers: CustomerModel[];
    public categories: CategoryModel[];
    public plan: PlanModel;

    public static getDummyModel(): ShopModel {
        return new ShopModel();
    }
}
```

This is my Data model

```
{
    "shop": {
        "name": "Develop Shop",
        "email": "sho3434p@develop.bs",
        "phone": "2343",
        "website": "dtewrtyty",
        "address": "rgtyyiuyouyip",
        "gst_number": "eytyw",
        "pan_number": "rywtywe",
        "tan_number": "ryeyru",
        "plan_id":1,
        "users_attributes": [{
            "email": "shop@develop.bs",
            "role": "user"
        }, {
            "email": "shop2@develop.bs",
            "role": "staff"
        }]
    }
}
```

I need to pass this JSON object as http post to the server.

For that i need to change the **users** array in data object to **users_attributes** while sending.

So please help me how can i achieve it. I am using Angular 6 for doing this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this should do the work (using lodash).

```
let shopModel = ShopModel.getDummyModel();
let shopObject = {
  "name": shopModel.name,
  "email": shopModel.email
}

shopObject['users_attributes'] = [];

_.forEach(shopModel.users, user => shopObject.users_attributes.push({'email': user.email, 'role': user.role}));
```

Comment: Thank you.. It works fine.  inputData.shop['users_attributes'] = users;